# Structuring data in Firebase mixing fields as ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database, nosql

I'm new using Firebase and NoSQL databases. I wonder if it's possible to do this:
Having an user database I want to fetch data by email or UID. Is it optimal to mix both fields as ID and later filter with `queryStartingAtValue` or `queryEndingAtValue`methods?

```
{
 "users": {
    "user1@gmail.comDjDJSADfgg": {
      dataUser1: ----- },

     "user2@gmail.comfmadaDkK": {
      dataUser2: ----- },

     "user3@gmail.com3Dkdjakdja4": {
      dataUser3: ----- },

     "user4@gmail.comKdsadASD": {
      dataUser4: ------ },
   }
}
```

Comment: You can do it, but is cleaner if you use only the UID and if you want to find a user by email  you can always make a query by child.  Also some people recommend not to use user personal info in the paths to avoid the possibility of someone try to probe for the existence of objects  and paths (depending on the configuration of your security rules) the probable downside is that you need to know the uid to access the user directly

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use `queryStartingAtValue` and `queryEndingAtValue`, this solution is not so clear, imagine that someone else reads your code (or even you after 6 months), would he/she knows what you meant by `queryStartingAtValue`? Probably not.

I think is clearer to use `orderByChild` and `equalTo`

e.g.

```
var ref = new Firebase("yourdb");

ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo("blahblah@gmail.com")
  .on( anEvent, function(snapshot) {   
       console.log(snapshot.key()); 
   });
```